# Battery indication on extremely simple 9V circuit

Tags: led, batteries

I have constructed a slug fence around my asparagus planting beds. Its a very simple circuit, 2 stainless wires 10mm apart going around the perimeter of the fence in a circle. Each circle is connected to a wire that ends up inside a silicone sealed plastic container with a 9V battery holder inside.

Slug crosses one wire, nothing happens. 
Slug crosses both wires, closes the circuit and gets a buzz.

9v doesnt really harm them but is enough for them to turn around and go somewhere else.

My problem is that I have no good way of knowing if the battery is charged or not. One night with no charge and my plants will get butchered.

I had an idea to put a LED on the circuit so I can close the circuit with my fingers and see if it lights up. What would that require? Are there any low power 9V LEDs or do I have to put a resistor somewhere? Wouldn't this resistor affect the current going through the slugs?

Happy for any suggestions! [image]

Comment: if your hand completes the circuit, LED will not have enough current to work

Comment: I'd just design a two-BJT, high impedance circuit (I'd be using \$2.2\:\text{M}\Omega\$ resistors in it.) It has low leakage on its own, but will readily detect your hand touching it. In fact, I already did this as a simple circuit to detect water on the bathroom floor (until I could buy and receive a cheap commercial unit to do the same work.) This included hysteresis in the design. The LED would be in the collector circuit of one of the two BJTs. A 3rd BJT might be needed if you wanted to add an alarm or something. For leakage related to outside use, though, I may adjust the trigger current.

Answer (score 0):

If you wire a led (say a 3.2V nominal blue led) to a 9v battery positive, and a wire to the 9v battery ground, lick your finger and touch the negative wire and the led cathode, it will act like a 1000 ohm resistor lighting up the led enough for you to know it's working. But to make it even easier, just like the battery. It normally wont kill you. I do it all the time to test 9V batteries. Not kidding.

That said let's avoid the unwise setups. Wire an led with a 1k ohm resistor and a push button to the battery. When you want to test the battery just press the button. No skin inbetween. You can put it anywhere between the two circles. And it wont affect the slugs deterrence as it will only draw current when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Do an experiment to figure out if 7.5V is sufficient for your needs. If yes, then buy rechargeable 9V battery from OKCell, like [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Quickbuying-Rechargeable-RC-Helicopter-Microphon/dp/B0754JXT6T).

[image]

It only gives out about 7.5V with no load, but it has built-in indicator activated by pressing a button.